# MarkLogic Data Search

Tags: marklogic

I want to build up document database using MarkLogic, currently I am trying to run some sample applications, from taking the files from web.
I came accross the FOAF.rdf (Friend of a friend) rdf files, but I am unable to implement it till the end & build a search engine on top of it!

Plz see the attached image for reference.

The main issue is that the data is not coming in the facets. 
I dont know what exactly I am missing.

Can anyone please help. ?

Is it necessary to convert the rdf to xml inorder to view the data into marklogics results page. ?

[This is how my application looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oALs.png)

Thanks & Regards
Swapneel

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the triples as described at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/loading.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search a document database, you might want to load some JSON or XML documents to search instead of triples.

The CIA world factbook is one small public dataset that's available as JSON or XML that's easy to understand.

https://github.com/twigkit/worldfactbook-dataset

On the MarkLogic developer site, you can get access to online training, which includes datasets to play around with:

http://www.marklogic.com/services/training/

Hoping that helps